# Integrating $\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been trying to understand the working of integrating $\displaystyle \frac{\sin x}{ \cos^2 x} dx$

I substitute with $u = \cos x$ and differentiate $\displaystyle \frac{du}{dx}$. I get $du = \sin x dx$, however the resources I have say it should be $-\sin x dx$.

I have checked a number of items and they indicate  the integral of $\displaystyle \cos(ax) dx = \frac{1}{a} \sin(ax) + C$.

I am unsure why in my original example integrating $\cos x$ is resulting in $-\sin x$. Where is the negative sign coming from ?

thanks

Comment: $u=\cos x\implies \mathrm du/\mathrm dx = -\sin x \implies \mathrm du = -\sin x \mathrm dx$?

Comment: ^^ yes this is what my resources show. However I believed the derivative of cos was sin ? So I am unsure why u = cos x doesn't derive to sin x ?.

Comment: I am differentiating in my comment, not integrating.

Comment: Note $du = u'(x)  dx$.

Comment: ah …embarrassing ..I was trying to integrate wasnt I when I should have been deriving …apologies

Comment: Don't worry that is a common mistake. I have given it a name for students I tutor. I warn them not to "differ-integrate." It happens quite often.

Comment: Change your question's title so that it matches the boy of the question.

Answer (score 3):

When you use "U" substitution, you look for a function and it's derivative present in the integrand. Once you choose a U, as in this case

$$u = \cos{x}$$ You have to differentiate $u$ to obtain $\frac{du}{dx}$. Once you have done this you have $$\frac{du}{dx}= -\sin{x}.$$ But, we are looking for a representation of our entire integrand in terms of $u$ rather than in terms of $x.$ So, we do some algebra $$-du =\sin{x}\ dx$$ and now we have everything that was once in terms of $x$ in terms of $u$ varied by the constant $-1$.

We can now rewrite the integral in terms of $u$ replacing our $x$ terms and making the integral simpler.

Answer (score 1):

In many of these basic cases you don't even need to substitute, just to *pay attention* : since

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2}=-\frac1x+C \implies \int\frac{f'}{f^2}dx=-\frac1f+C$$

whenever $\;f\;$ is a differentiable function (why? Just apply the Chain Rule) .

In our case, $\;\sin x=-(\cos x)'\;$ , so we can put

$$\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}dx=-\int\frac{(\cos x)'}{\cos^2x}dx=\frac1{\cos x}+C$$

and we're done.

Basically, one has to *identify* the expression $\;\frac{f'}f\;$ in the integral, and then use basic integration on it.